# List the latest 5 tweets in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on a basic twitter clone in rails to help learn. In my index view for users, I want the latest 5 tweets by those users to be displayed. What's the best way to do that?

This is my user index view right now:

```
<ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
        <%=user.name %>
        <ul>
            <% user.tweets.each do |tweet| %>
            <li>
                <%=tweet.message%>
            <% end %>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <br>
        <%= link_to "View Full Feed", user %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to "Return Home", welcome_index_path %>
```

Right now it will display all the tweets, but like I said, I just want it to display the 5 latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace your code `user.tweets.each` with:

```
user.tweets.order(created_at: :desc).take(5).each
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `order` and `limit` to retrieve the latest five tweets.

```
user.tweets.order(created_at: :desc).limit(5)
```